# Spark: connection errors during RDD count

Tags: amazon-web-services, count, apache-spark, rdd

I have a Spark job which works fine for 150G dataset. However, when I tried to increase the amount of data to around 600G, I kept getting the following errors, and it seems to be failing at: `myRDD.count()` at line:

```
at com.myproject.myJob.MyProcessor$.process(MyProcessor.scala:45)
```

---

Does anyone have any suggestion about how to resolve this problem? I am running on AWS-EMR-4.1.0-Spark 1.5.0. Thanks!

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1280)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1455)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1813)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1826)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1839)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1910)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1121)
    at com.myproject.myJob.MyProcessor$.process(MyProcessor.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:525)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to ip-10-153-139-23.ec2.internal:48632
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:193)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.access$200(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher$1.run(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:107)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:649)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:209)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:207)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1097)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:471)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:456)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:471)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:456)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:471)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:456)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:438)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:908)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:203)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$2.run(Bootstrap.java:166)
```

Comment: from the exception stack , it clearly shows that "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to ip-10-153-139-23.ec2.internal:48632"   anything wrong in the network configuration?

Comment: I am running on AWS EMR cluster, didn't change any configuration myself. Should I actually do any network configuration when I start the cluster? Thanks!